# Find a file matching with certain pattern and giving that file name as value to a variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am finding a way to get the filename assigned to a variable in my shell script. But my file has naming format as **file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt**.

Here the numbers may change sometimes, now how can i assign this filename to a variable. Any regex can be used?  or **grep**? or **find**? or **file**?

My directory consists of following files:

```
file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt
newFile-1.0.0.txt
sample.txt
```

My script **sc.sh**:

```
file_path="/home/user/handsOn"
var=$file_path/file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt
newLocation=/new_path
cp $var $newLocation
```

Now the file version changes sometimes. My script should work for any version number.

How can I assign the matched filename to variable? Help me out. TIA

Comment: please clarify, what already exists, what do you want to happen, please give an example.

Comment: @Yaron Example added. I hope my question is clear now. Please help me out

Comment: Will you at any point in time end up with multiple `SNAPSHOT.txt` files? If so, which one should be picked? If you want to pick the latest one, do the filenames sort properly?

Comment: Just copy *SNAPSHOT* ?

Comment: yes, there will be only one SNAPSHOT with any version number. My concern is how can i handle the version number

Comment: You don't need to. As _Spike_ suggests just copy `*SNAPSHOT` e.g. `cp /file-path/*SNAPSHOT.txt /new-path` as the glob will always expand to the right file name.

Comment: lets say there is also a file named as **file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt.bak**. Then in that case how can we do.

Comment: `*SNAPSHOT*` could be a solution - will handle all files containing SNAPSHOT

Comment: but i want only  **file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt** need to be selected, not all the files

Comment: `*SNAPSHOT*` or even better `*SNAPSHOT.*` will not select all files. Will select all files containing `anychar` + `SNAPSHOT` + `.` + `any extension`

Comment: How can you do what ? The glob `*SNAPSHOT.txt` will ignore your `.bak` file so where's the problem ?

Comment: @don_crissti getting the filename assigned to var, while runtime.

Comment: `set -- *SNAPSHOT.txt; var=$1; set --`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution after many trial and error methods:

```
cd $file_path && fVar=$(find -type f -name 'file-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-SNAPSHOT.txt');

echo $fVar    # output is like ./file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt

fT=${fVar:2}  # removing first two characters'./'

echo "$fT"    # output is file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt
```

Thanks [Rakesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/218374/rakesh-sharma) for contributing your [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361695/227732), it helped me.

Comment: Giving to find the optiion `-printf %f\\n` will return the results without ./ in front.

Answer (score 20):

Let say your file is following this pattern file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt so it can be like **file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt** or **file-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.txt** or **file-1.5.1-SNAPSHOT.txt** etc. then you can get the files using find command like this :-

```
find . -type f -iname "*SNAPSHOT.txt"
```

It will give you all the files which ends with **SNAPSHOT.txt** and then you can use it to do your work.

Dot(**.**) in **find** can be a parent directory which should contains the file. Like as

```
find ~/my_files/ -type f -iname "*SNAPSHOT.txt"
```

Comment: This will fail if more than one `*SNAPSHOT.txt` is found

Comment: This is a 50% solution. You need to advise how to handle each result that will be returned by find in order to execute the real copy.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're trying to do is to copy only the last version.

```
#!/bin/bash
oldlocation="/file_path/"
newlocation="/new_path/"

cd "$oldlocation"

#Get the last version
file="$(ls  *SNAPSHOT.txt | sort -V | tail -n1)"

cp -v "$file" "$newlocation" && echo "Everything is ok"
```

Comment: Just added sort -V that is working fine in all tests that i do.

Comment: With almost 2K Rating, i am sure you have received comments before why is not good to parse output of ls (i just don't have the correct link to redirect you there).

Comment: Sorry dont have a good english, can you explain what is "Is"?

Comment: I talk about output of `ls` command that you use in your solution. Breaks easily (i.e in case of spaces in filename).

Comment: I think not in this case. Sort and tail will threat the output as lines, spaces does not matter. Also the name of the file never changes, but only the version. Maybe im wrong, but considering this case the script will works.

Comment: But what i asked is to get the filename to a variable

Comment: The filename is being saved into the variable $file. You want to get the filename from a variable?

Answer (score 3):

selection happens via the -name option and action is via the -exec option.

```
find . -type f -name '*-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-SNAPSHOT.txt' -exec sh -c '
  file=$1
  # do what you want with $file as many times as you want
' {} {} \;
```

Comment: How can i assign the filename matching to this pattern to a variable, so that i have multiple operations to do with that variable which is having the matched filename.

Comment: i may have files like:
**file-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.txt**,

**newFIle-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.txt**

I need to figure it out a way to get the filename into var, sometimes it may be  for file-1.2.0 or for sometimes it may for newFile-1.3.0. There must be a pattern for getting it. Right?

Comment: `fileVar="";
find . -type f -name '*-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-SNAPSHOT.txt' -exec sh -c 'fileVar=$1' {} {} \;
echo "$fileVar";`

but its printing nothing

Comment: earlier the `cp` command worked, but now this variable is not getting assigned.